# C invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)?

Tags: arrays, c, string, macros, char

In C I have:

```
filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name
```

Now I want to add the following string next to it: "new"

I tried:

```
filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name + "new"
```

but this won't compile and I get:

```
readelf.c:6807:83: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
  filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name : filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name+"new")
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ^
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If you want to concatenate strings, there are functions for that (see `strcat` for example).  `+` is arithmetic operator

Comment: The compiler error is self-explanatory. Please study the chapter about C strings in your favourite C book.

Comment: What types are the members that are involved here? Already the first snippet looks fishy.

Answer (score 1):

`(X)->sh_name+"new"` `+` in C does not concatenate the strings. It tries to add pointer to pointer which is invalid.

You need to use function [strcat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) or [strncat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html)

> Sorry These functions affect the strings but I want a new one –

it is so simple:

```
char *strcatAlloc(const char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2)
{
    size_t s1len;
    char *newstring;

    if(s1 && s2)
    {
        s1len = strlen(s1);
        newstring = malloc(s1len + strlen(s2) + 1);
        if(newstring)
        {
            strcpy(newstring, s1);
            strcpy(newstring + s1len, s2);
        }
    }
    return newstring;
}

int main(void)
{
    // you should check if the function fails. Omitted for the example clarity
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("hello ", "world"));
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("", "world"));
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("hello ", ""));
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("", ""));

    //you should free allocated space
}
```

or version where you can pass your buffer (it will allocate memory if that buffer is NULL)

```
char *strcatAlloc(const char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, char *buff)
{
    size_t s1len;

    if(s1 && s2)
    {
        s1len = strlen(s1);
        if(!buff) buff = malloc(s1len + strlen(s2) + 1);
        if(buff)
        {
            strcpy(buff, s1);
            strcpy(buff + s1len, s2);
        }
    }
    return buff;
}

int main(void)
{

    char s[100];
    // you should check if the function fails. Omitted for the example
     printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("hello ", "world", NULL));
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("", "world", NULL));
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("hello ", "", s));  //you can pass your own large enough buffer 
    printf("`%s`\n", strcatAlloc("", "", NULL));

    //you should free allocaated space
}
```

Comment: I assume, `sh_name` is an integer. Otherwise already the first snippet wouldn't compile. That code seems to come from `readelf.c`

Comment: @Gerhardh even if it is not it will be the same error only repeated twice in the same line :) The answer is the same

Comment: Sorry These functions affect the strings but I want a new one

Comment: @daniel you must take care about freeing that new memory area after you don't need it any more.

Comment: @Gerhardh it is in my comments to the code

Comment: @0___________ yes, I just wanted to emphasize that for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper way to concatenate strings.

If you want to add the result to existing buffer, use `strcat()` to concatenate strings.

```
char buffer[1024000]; /* enough size */
strcpy(buffer, filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name);
strcat(buffer, "new");
```

You also can use `snprintf()` to put the result of concatenation in a buffer.

```
char buffer[1024000]; /* enough size */
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s%s",
    filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name, "new");
```

To print the result to the standard output, use two `%s` format specifier to print the two strings in a row.

```
printf("%s%s",
    filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name, "new");
```

If the string `"new"` is fixed, also you can do like this:

```
printf("%snew",
    filedata->string_table + (X)->sh_name);
```

Comment: char buffer[1024000]; ????? why not `strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1`.

Comment: Note that [the default stack size on Microsoft Windows is 1 MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size), so `char buffer[1024000];` may cause a stack overflow on that platform.

Comment: @0___________ Because some compilers are stuck on 1989's ANSI C and can't handle VLAs (\*cough\* MSVC \*cough\*)

Comment: @AndrewHenle then `malloc` is your friend. BTW using a reference to the local object is UB, so this idea is double wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate `strings` or `char` using the operator `+`. Use `strncat()` or `snprintf()`.

Comment: Sorry These functions affect the strings but I want a new one

Comment: You can use `strcpy` to create a new string.

Comment: Thanks! I rephrased my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C doesn't have an actual string type - strings are stored in arrays of `char`, and C doesn't define the `+` or `=` operators for array types.

You can append strings to a character buffer using `strcat` or `strncat`:

```
char foo[] = "This is ";
char bar[] = "a test";
char target[ sizeof foo + sizeof bar ];

strcpy( target, foo ); // copies contents of foo to target buffer
strcat( target, bar ); // appends contents of bar to target buffer
```

The target buffer must be large enough to accommodate the final string including the terminator.  In this example, we took the sizes (not lengths!) of `foo` and `bar` which are 9 and 7 respectively (including the string terminators).  Note that this would not work if they were declared as

```
char *foo = "This is ";
char *bar = "a test";
```

because `sizeof foo` would only give us the size of the pointer object, not the size of the string to which it points.  In that case you'd have to get the size at runtime using `strlen`.  If you're using a version that supports VLAs (C99 or later), you could simply do

```
char *foo = "This is ";
char *bar = "a test";

char target[ strlen( foo ) + strlen( bar ) + 1];
```

If not, you'd have to allocate your buffer dynamically:

```
char *target = malloc( strlen( foo ) + strlen( bar ) + 1 );
```

and you'd have to remember to `free` it when you're done.

---

If you have a mix of string and non-string types, you can use `sprintf`:

```
char *name = "blah";
int number = 42;

sprintf( target, "%s-%d", name, number ); // writes "blah-42" to target buffer
```

Again, the target buffer must be large enough to store the resulting string plus the terminator.

Comment: `"that supports VLAs (C99 or later)"` -- Note that C11-compliant compilers are not required to support VLAs. VLAs have been downgraded to an optional feature in C11.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: True on both counts.  As for using a size argument, in my own code I typically do all the sanity checks for buffer sizing before getting to the `sprintf` statement itself, so I tend not to use size arguments.

Comment: I deleted my second comment (the one about using `%.*s%` instead of `%s` in the format string) before you answered, because you are right that the sanity checks must be performed beforehand anyway, when using `strcat`. Therefore, my comment about recommending additional size safe-guards when using the function `sprintf` did not seem appropriate. That is why I withdrew my comment.